# transfer files!!! from a unix server to a linux server

Tags: linux, file, unix, copy, scp

I used scp -prv command to copy directory/files (/usr/local/scripts) from a unix server to a linux server. Copy worked, however, it created another directory inside the scripts (/usr/local/scripts/scripts). How do I make it, what do I delete, so it just stays /usr/local/scripts?

Comment: "urgent" = "too localised" (in time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cd /usr/local/scripts/scripts
 cp -r * ../.
 //Check to make sure it looks good
 rm -r /usr/local/scripts/scripts
```

This is super basic....

Comment: sorry Constantin... I am a windows guy trying to become a linux person. I do appreciate your help

Comment: No need for apologies, I was simply pointing out these commands and situations are extremely basic in nature.  If I may suggest doing a few linux tutorials.  I do understand the need for urgency though.  Happy linuxing.

Answer (score 0):

`scp -prv /usr/local/scripts host:/usr/local/` for proper copying, what Constantin said for cleaning up.

Comment: Well i already did the copying part, do i need to rm -rf the /usr/local/scripts/scripts? and run scp again

Comment: Both of your answers helped ... I had to rm -rf /usr/local/scripts/scripts and once it was deleted ... I just ran scp again to make this work ... btw my reason to ask was because:
mv /usr/local/scripts/scripts /usr/local/scripts
gave me the output that both of the files were the same, when they are clearly not the same... I was under the impression that if i moved it, it should have taken care of it and should have removed the /scripts/scripts

Comment: In that situation use -f (for force), it'll do what you tell it and not pretend like it knows better.

Comment: Well the girl who needed this to be copied over wanted me to do it infront of her so she can see it ... therefore I did not use the -f flag.